# Installing c++ standard library files on ubuntu

Tags: c++, g++

To give a background, there was a tuple file in /usr/include/c++ which got corrupted. So my compiler used to give input/output error. I downloaded tuple file from web from c++ library and replaced it with my corrupted file. But now error was different. My professor asked me to reinstall my library. So for that i removed /usr/include/c++ folder that had all library files. Now when i reinstalled g++ i thought it would automatically get the header files i.e /usr/include/c++ folder but i was wrong. It does not get installed. I have tried to find solution and people saying install -dev version etc but i could not find the commands to install those header files. Kindly help.

Comment: *"downloaded tuple file from web from c++ library and replaced it"* You should be very careful when doing that. There are several implementations of C++ standard library, and each has different versions. Files from different versions/implementations might be incompatible with each other.

Comment: I did not know that but now damage is done. I am not able to install /usr/include/c++ files even though i used sudo apt to delete the compiler and then installing it.

Comment: If you don't figure it out, you can always reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your command line and type the following:

```
sudo apt purge g++
```

and after that enter

```
sudo apt install g++
```

and finally type in

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After that you can try to get the headers back by getting libg++ with

```
sudo apt install libg++
```

if that doesn't help, you can also try these two commands.
First type:

```
dpkg --search /usr/include/c++
```

to get all the packages that have installed files to this directory.
After that you can reinstall all of these found packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall
```

Comment: Not solving. Still when i compile my main function it doesnot recognize iostream header. And still there is no directory usr/include/c++.

Comment: try ```sudo apt install libg++``` instead

Comment: The run-time library for the GNU C++ compiler, g++.
libg++ is no longer maintained, use libstd++ instead if possible. See here:
https://melodict.com/libg%2B%2B
and the source:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.whereis_old